# Mail Gun not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku

Newbie here! Have been watching videos on how to create web apps. using Ruby on Rails and cloud9 as the development environment. My training assignment is to create a saas app. This app has a contact form that visitors can use to enter their comments and contact info. The goal is to set up an automatic email that will let me know when someone submits their contact info on the website. When I got to the point of the training that transfers my code to the production environment (Heroku) I set up Mail Gun, but when I test the form out and hit submit button, it says that an error occurred and I should check the logs for more details. I have checked my code and can't find anything wrong. Hoping someone has run into a similar problem and can offer suggestions.

Comment: there was nothing logged for the error unfortunately.

Comment: Found it! There was a spacing issues in my contacts_controller.rb file.